# Anybody knows how to change the rplidar motor rate?

Tags: ros, lidar, rplidar, sensor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I bought a rplidar laser and I want to control the frequency or rate of my sensor. Anybody knows how I can do this?

Thanks in advance.

Carlos

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217540/anybody-knows-how-to-change-the-rplidar-motor-rate?/) by [ingcavh](https://answers.ros.org/users/20373/ingcavh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2015-09-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://www.seeedstudio.com/document/pdf/rplidar_devkit_manual_en.pdf - you control the motor PWM

Mark

---

Originally posted by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) with karma: 1834 on 2015-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0